# Read/Write int Binary File in C error

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I am facing an error reading/writing to a binary file in C. The issue is:
- I write an int (e.g. 2) to a file using fwrite
- I try read this int from a file using fread
- When I read it, it doesn't come out as 2, but rather some long number e.g. 967899906 or 2071332354 or 1030372866 (always different).

I write to a binary file in C like this:

```
FILE * writeFile = fopen("test.bin","wb");

//test int vars
int test1 = 1;
int test2 = 2;
int test3 = 3;

//writing some ints to binary file
fwrite(&test1,1,1, writeFile);
fwrite(&test2,1,1, writeFile);
fwrite(&test3,1,1, writeFile);

fclose(writeFile);
```

I then read from the file like this:

```
FILE *readFile = fopen("test.bin","rb");
int data;
while(fread(&data,1,1, readFile)==1){
   printf("%d", data); //here it will output some random number
}
fclose(readFile);
```

Comment: `fwrite(&test1,1,1, writeFile);` --> `fwrite(&test1,sizeof(test1),1, writeFile);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fwrite](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) wants, as second parameter, size of data to write, so in your case `sizeof(int)`

Same thing for `fread`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     FILE * writeFile = fopen("test.bin","wb");

     if (writeFile != NULL)
     {
         //test int vars
         int test1 = 1;
         int test2 = 2;
         int test3 = 3;

         //writing some ints to binary file
         fwrite(&test1,sizeof(test1),1, writeFile);
         fwrite(&test2,sizeof(test2),1, writeFile);
         fwrite(&test3,sizeof(test3),1, writeFile);

         fclose(writeFile);
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Error opening file to write: ");
         return 1;
     }


     FILE *readFile = fopen("test.bin","rb");
     if (readFile != NULL)
     {
         int data;
         while(fread(&data,sizeof(data),1, readFile)==1){
            printf("%d\n", data);
         }
         fclose(readFile);
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Error opening file to read: ");
         return 1;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Hint: always test if `fopen` succeed.

**EDIT**

To use 1 byte variable, as commented, just use `uint8_t` variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
     FILE * writeFile = fopen("test.bin","wb");

     if (writeFile != NULL)
     {
         //test int vars
         uint8_t test1 = 1;
         uint8_t test2 = 2;
         uint8_t test3 = 3;

         //writing some ints to binary file
         fwrite(&test1,sizeof(test1),1, writeFile);
         fwrite(&test2,sizeof(test2),1, writeFile);
         fwrite(&test3,sizeof(test3),1, writeFile);

         fclose(writeFile);
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Error opening file to write: ");
         return 1;
     }


     FILE *readFile = fopen("test.bin","rb");
     if (readFile != NULL)
     {
         uint8_t data;
         while(fread(&data,sizeof(data),1, readFile)==1){
            printf("%d\n", data);
         }
         fclose(readFile);
     }
     else
     {
         perror("Error opening file to read: ");
         return 1;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am deliberately trying to save each int as 1 byte (as the max values are 255). How will this impact? Actually, I should make those test vars uint8_t

Comment: Yes, simplyest way

Answer (score 0):

LPs is right about that if you have a range of `0 <= x <= 255`, you should consider `uint8_t`.

However, if you do want to use an `int`, the reason you are probably getting garbage is because

```
fread(&data,1,1, readFile)==1)
```

reads a single byte of data and puts it at the location specified by the pointer. In your case, this will be the lowest byte of `data`. Ints are typically 4 bytes long so the other 3 bytes will be unchanged. What are the other three bytes? Well, in your case, they could be anything because `data` is uninitialised on the stack.